# Окончание существительного после числа 21

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, как писать правильно: "в течение 21 рабочего дня" или "рабочих дней"?

Answer (score 4):

Корректно: *в течение двадцати одного рабочего дня.* Форма род. множ. используется при всех количественных числительных в косвенных падежах за исключением тех, что оканчиваются единицей: с ними употребляется форма род. ед. Но если этой единице предшествует ещё одна единица (11, 111, 211 и т.д.), используется вновь форма род. множ. А если числительное стоит в именительном падеже, всё будет ещё чуть сложнее. Но не буду запутывать. :)

Answer (score 1):

Да тут трудно запутаться. Не надо к цифрам апеллировать, лучше к словам.
 ;)
Всего три варианта последнего слова: 1. один; 2. два, три, четыре; 3. всё остальное (пять, деcять, одиннадцать, девятнадцать, двадцать, девяносто, сто, пятьсот, тысяча, миллион...)

... один день, ... одного дня, ... одному дню...
... два (три, четыре) дня, ... двух  дней, ... двум  дням,
... одиннадцать (девятнадцать, двадцать, девяносто, сто) дней, ... одиннадцати  дней, дням, одиннадцати дням... и т.д.

Последние две последовательности отличаются только именительным падежом. Это объясняется историческими причинами. "(Два) дня" - особая форма двойственного числа, в современном язвке совпавшая с родительным единственного.