# Как будет правильно?

Tags: грамматика

В течение последующих 31 *дней* или *дня*.

Comment: Повтор вопроса http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1485/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-21

Comment: Смущает наличие слова "последующих". С чем оно согласуется?Его нет в том вопросе, на который здесь ссылаются. Было бы полезно дать полный ответ.